# Drawing on QGraphicsScene from a QGraphicsItem derived class

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am working on a RPG game in Qt, using the Graphics View Framework. I have create a class, "Player", which inherits QGraphicsItem. Now, i am trying to make an "attack" animation, so everytime i press the space key, there would be an animation in front of the character. I have already implemented the moving animation, using the "advance()" function.

So, every time i press space, the "is_attacking" variable becomes true. Every 85 miliseconds, the program checks if "is_attacking" is true, and if it is, the animation will advance(draw next frame) and update. When all frames have been used, "is_attacking" becomes false.

The problem is that i can't use the "Player" class to draw the animation. QGraphicsItem is independent and have it's own coordinate system. I've aleardy finished the attack system but i can't draw the animation onto the scene.

```
void Player::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget){

painter->drawPixmap(QRect(0, 0, 32, 32), *pixmap, QRect(position.x(), position.y(), 32, 32));

if(its_attacking()){
    switch(pos){
case NORTH: // draw animation frame to x, y - 32
break;
case SOUTH: // draw animation frame to x, y + 32
break;
case WEST: // draw animation frame to x - 32, y
break;
case EAST: // draw animation frame to x + 32, y

     }


   } 

}
```

How could i use "paint()" from a QGraphicsItem to draw onto the QGraphicsScene which the item belongs to ?

Answer (score 0):

[`paint()`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsitem.html#paint) is used in order to paint the item in **local coordinates**. What you need in order to change the item's position is the [`setPos()`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsitem.html#setPos) function which sets the item's position in parent's coordinates.

The animation should not be handled in the `paint()` function (except if you want to change item's position) but in the slot called at timer's timeout:

```
// Slot called at 85 ms timer's timeout
void Player::timerTimeoutSlot()
{
   if(its_attacking()){
      switch(pos){
        case NORTH: // draw animation frame to x, y - 32
            setPos(QPointF(pos().x(), pos().y()-32);
            break;
        case SOUTH: // draw animation frame to x, y + 32
            setPos(QPointF(pos().x(), pos().y()+32);
            break;
        case WEST: // draw animation frame to x - 32, y
            setPos(QPointF(pos().x()-32, pos().y());
            break;
        case EAST: // draw animation frame to x + 32, y
            setPos(QPointF(pos().x()+32, pos().y());
            break;
     }
   }
}
```

Notice that in order to enable signals/slots you should inherit from [`QGraphicsObject`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsobject.html) instead of [`QGraphicsItem`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsitem.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how could i draw the animation frame from a slot ?

Comment: You will use both paint() in order to draw the animation, and from the slot you will change the position of the item

Comment: But the animation is just a sprite sheet, a QPixmap. How could i move the pixmap ? The pixmap is the sheet, so i only draw a part of it.

Comment: The player is moving or not?

Comment: No, i mean the player has a moving animation but it doesn't interfere with the attack animation.